# Alexa developer console simulator returning wrong intent

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I'm having a problem with the Alexa Simulator on the Amazon Developer Console. When I try using certain phrases to trigger an intent, the simulator responds with the skill's opening message instead of processing the intent. It's strange because I haven't made any recent changes to the intent that's causing this.

Has anyone else faced a similar issue? Can you suggest any steps I can take to figure out what's going wrong and fix it?

Thanks a lot for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Alexa uses your skill's interaction model to pick the intent closest to the users uttered request. Since you're seeing intents being incorrectly triggered, I recommend you review the following common pitfalls to interaction model design:

1. Remove any unnecessary custom slots. If you have sample utterances that are mostly or entirely composed of custom slots, take a look at what words those slots are referring to and ask whether you need those words to be passed to your back-end as values. If not, then removing them may improve your skill's recognition and reliability.
2. Make sure custom slots and sample utterances contain dictionary words. If the words contained in a sample utterance are not dictionary words, or are words in a language other than the one chosen on the skill's language tab, that could reduce the reliability of Alexa's ability to pick the intent associated with that sample utterance.
3. Make sure that sample utterances don't duplicate launch phrases or reserved connecting words. For example, starting your sample utterance with "from" or "ask."
4. Leave out extra punctuation, such as hyphens, as the users won’t say this out loud.  The only time you would want to add punctuation is after a single letter, for example, if you were writing "the a. b. c. song". “30s” might be better understood by writing “thirties”. Please also make sure spelling is correct- for example, I believe I saw “rupees” misspelled as “rupess” in one utterance, and “help mw” instead of “me”.